# How to properly close a Net::SSH connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, net-ssh

Many articles demonstrate `Net::SSH` by using a block, such as the following:

```
Net::SSH.start("host", "user") do |ssh|
  ssh.exec! "cp /some/file /another/location"
  hostname = ssh.exec!("hostname")

  ssh.open_channel do |ch|
    ch.exec "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' ls" do |ch, success|
      abort "could not execute sudo ls" unless success

      ch.on_data do |ch, data|
        print data
        if data =~ /sudo password: /
          ch.send_data("password\n")
        end
      end
    end
  end

  ssh.loop
end
```

However, I am actually using it in a Ruby class and calling it from various other functions and methods within my application. For example, I have an `SSHCommand` class that does the following:

```
class SSHCommand
    def initialize
        ...
        @ssh = establish_ssh
        ...
    end

    def establish_ssh
        ssh = Net::SSH.start(
            @ip, 'root',
            :host_key => 'ssh-rsa',
            :encryption => 'aes256-ctr',
            :keys => [@key],
            :compression => "zlib@openssh.com",
            :port => @port
        )
        return ssh
    end
    def execute(command)
        results = String.new
        results = run_cmd(command)
        if results.include? "no matches found"
            results = ""
        end
        return results
    end
end
```

and to execute a command over an SSH connection, I just simply run the following:

```
ssh = SSHCommand.new
ssh.execute("ifconfig")
```

How do I actually terminate this SSH session? I noticed that when my Sidekiq workers in Ruby on Rails are completed, I get the following message:

```
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.
```

The reason I avoided using a block is because I wanted to have multiple commands sent from my worker to be executed via an already-established SSH connection.

Am I not using this the way it's intended, or is there an actual way to close this connection when I've completed my tasks?

Comment: You could rewrite your initializer to use a block too, e.g. `SSHCommand.new { |ssh| ssh.execute("ifconfig") ... }`

Comment: Is there not a way to close it the way its written?

Comment: Well, your `SSHCommand` class don't know when the worker is done sending commands, does it? Wrapping the worker's code in a block is the easiest way I can think of. Another approach is to utilize [`ObjectSpace.define_finalizer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/ObjectSpace.html#define_finalizer-method) but a plain block is much cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Gotcha. Makes sense. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start an SSH connection without a block, you'll get a `Net::SSH::Connection::Session`, on which you should eventually call [close](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/net-ssh/net-ssh/Net/SSH/Connection/Session#close-instance_method).

Here is a [Net::SSH demonstration program](https://github.com/applandinc/land-of-applets/tree/master/how-to-properly-close-a-netssh-connection_62643718), plus some images and links to interactive visualizations of how Net::SSH works overall, including `close`.